# android studio keeps stopping - Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm getting an Application Has Stopped Error.
I'm just starting out so I don't know much about this.
I looked at other threads but couldn't find anything similar to my code can you help me?

```
 Process: com.example.andromeda, PID: 5300
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andromeda/com.example.andromeda.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class EditText
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class EditText
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class EditText
         Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AndroMeda"
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
            at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:133)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:375)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1265)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:93)
```

when the application was run, it gave an error and these red texts appeared, I did not know what to do because I did not understand By the way This is my main activity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ad" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/soyad"
            android:inputType="@string/app_name"
            android:text="@string/soyad" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I think these are the required files

Answer (score 1):

Either remove `android:inputType="@string/app_name"` or set it to a valid value, such as `text`. `AndroMeda` (the apparent value of `@string/app_name`) is not a valid value [for `inputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType).

Answer (score 0):

replace `android:inputType="@string/app_name"`
with

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: This is what the other answer said three hours earlier.